# Do we only use cross-validation for hyperparameter tuning?

Tags: regression, python, cross-validation, validation

I am still unsure why we must use cross-validation here to validate the model, or it may be unnecessary.

Is it correct to use like indicated below? or do we have to combine it with hyperparameter tuning?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_new, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=iteration)
        
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6, random_state=iteration, shuffle=True)
pls = PLSRegression(n_components=n_components, scale=False)

    for train_index, val_index in skf.split(X_train, y_train):
        X_train_fold, X_val_fold = X_train[train_index], X_train[val_index]
        y_train_fold, y_val_fold = y_train[train_index], y_train[val_index]

        pls.fit(X_train_fold, y_train_fold)
        
y_pred = pls.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.round(y_pred).astype(int)
        
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
scores1.append(accuracy)

accuracy_scores_mean.append(np.mean(scores1))
accuracy_scores_std.append(np.std(scores1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross-validation is a method for estimating the operational performance of a method of constructing a model.  It can be used for essentially any task for which you need a performance estimate.  Hyper-parameter tuning is one use of a performance estimate (we tune the model to maximise performance).  Note however if we use cross-validation to tune parameters it no longer provides an unbiased performance estimate (i.e. it may be an unreliable guide to operational performance).  So if you want to use cross-validation for hyper-parameter tuning and you need an unbiased performance estimate you need something like nested cross-validation.  Mrs Marsupial and I wrote a (hopefully) accessible paper on this topic:

G. C. Cawley and N. L. C. Talbot, Over-fitting in model selection and subsequent selection bias in performance evaluation, Journal of Machine Learning Research, 2010. Research, vol. 11, pp. 2079-2107, July 2010.  ([pdf](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf))

Sometimes we want a performance estimate simply so we know how well the system is likely to perform in operation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed comment.
So then, the method in the code seems acceptable. The aim there is to learn from cross-validation and then testing on unseen dataset. 
However, I checked it out with or without it. If I do not include cross-validation part, the model gives a little bit higher accuracy.
At the end, I felt confused. My aim is to use cross validation to learn from itself, then testing on unseen set.

Comment: @vdu16 I am not a python programmer, but I think the code is incorrect because the error on the "validation" folds does not seem to be evaluated.  Your loop is fitting a model to the training set of each fold, but then not doing anything with it.  Also the test performance is evaluated on the model from the last iteration of the cross-validation loop, rather than a model trained on the entire training set.

Comment: Because my interest is to make the model performance much better after it learns from cross validation. Therefore, I focus on model performance on unseen test set. In addition to that, I did not fit the model to the entire train set because it may learn the whole dataset, and it can create biased-very good model performance.

Comment: @vdu16 Cross-validation is just a method of estimating performance, by itself it does not improve the model.  It can be used in conjunction with a method such as grid search to tune the hyper-parameters, which probably *will* make the model better, but that is not what you have done in the code fragment.  Also cross-validation is a method of estimating the performance of a **method** for creating a model.  In each loop of the cross-validation you need to perform all of the steps you take to build the operational model, so in general, after estimating performance using ...

Comment: ... cross-validation, we then build the operational model using the same procedure using all of the available data (X_train and y_train) in your code.

Comment: so then, why does the code give different response when I delete the cross validation part, and fit the model to X_train? This part --> pls.fit(X_train_fold, y_train_fold), when I do pls.fit(X_train, y_train)

Comment: @vdu16 because at the moment it is giving the performance of a model trained on the last cross-validation fold.  You will get a different answer if you train on the whole training set because it is a larger set of data.

Comment: can I kindly ask what your possible code would be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147659/discussion-between-dikran-marsupial-and-vdu16).